# Are shopping recommendations off-topic or banned on every single Stack Exchange Site?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I really wanted to find a game, and I asked about it, since I couldn't find it.
Later my question was flagged as off-topic.

So now I am asking: Do we have any place in here (Stack Exchange) where I could ask about finding a game I am searching for?

Comment: You can try to ask on the chat rooms of relevant sites.

Comment: That's generally how we do it at Arqade.  We point 'em at the Bridge for recommendation type questions.  Unfortunately, most often, the people asking the questions don't have the rep to actually talk in chat.

Answer (score 5):

They are generally off-topic on most Stack Exchange sites.

The sites that do allow them have very strict rules about what is allowed (check the help center of a site).

As far as I know, recommendations are allowed on Photography, Software Recommendations (duh!) and Tex.

I don't know if Software Recommendations allows games.

For rationale about why these are generally off-topic, see [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: If the Software Recommendations doesn't allow talking about games, is it a possibility to create a site which "lets" recommend games?

Comment: @Damaskox You could propose such a site on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Damaskox - what Louis said. I can't find one there (that's where people can suggest new sites - if they get enough following, they happen)

Comment: @Louis I just asked about this in Software Recommendations. If they won't accept Game Recommendations, I will think about proposing it.